# find out which shell tcsh/bash/etc. is running when eval is used on script

Tags: bash, shell, eval, csh, tcsh

I have a shell script that exports variables to be used in tool setup for a multiuser environment. As different projects (history of 100+ projects) use different setups, my script sets variables for different shell kinds.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

#some XY_VAR setting happening here

case "$1" in

'-c')
    echo "setenv XY $XY_VAR;"
    ;;

'-b')
    echo "export XY=$XY_VAR;"
    ;;

esac
```

when used in a project's script, it is evaled like this

```
eval `set_my_vars -c` #when using (t)c-shell
eval `set_my_vars -b` #when using bash
```

My question is can I make the script detect the shell it is evaled from and input that to the case statement?

`ps -hp $$`

doesn't work when the script is evaled, this was my first idea (with awk of course). I have found multiple ways where people wanted to detect in which shell they are running in, but all I have found fail when using eval.

Can anybody help? Maybe I am just to stupid to find the solution on my own.

Thanks and best regards
rws

Comment: in theory correct, but you can still set variables and be in other shells. If BASH is set in a tcsh my script would take the wrong case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` refers to the *current* process; which in your case is the shell that gets spawned by the backticks. So what you need to do is get the pid of the process that spawned the subshell: the parent process. An example might be:

```
comm=$(ps -ho comm $(ps -ho ppid $$))
echo "echo \"$comm\""
```

This first runs `ps -ho ppid $$` to get the parent pid, and then runs another `ps -ho comm` to get the command name from the parent pid.

And then using:

```
eval `./sourceme`
```

Will print the expected value:

```
[~]% eval `./sourceme`
zsh

$ sh
$ eval `./sourceme`
sh

$ csh
% eval `./sourceme`
csh

% bash
[~]$ eval `./sourceme`
bash

[~]$ osh
osh$ eval `./sourceme`
osh
```

The fish shell requires slightly different syntax though:

```
osh$ fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
martin@e585 ~> eval `./sourceme`
fish: Unknown command: `./sourceme`
martin@e585 ~> eval (./sourceme)
fish
```

I only tested this on Linux; since your `ps` example gives an error on my system ("unsupported SysV option") it looks like you're probably not using Linux(or a Linux with a different `ps`?) so you may need to frob with the commands a bit, but this should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Also, if you run this through another script you may need to get the parent of the parent.

---

If you are using Linux then another option would be using the /proc filesystem:

```
ppid=$(cat "/proc/$$/status" | grep ^PPid: | awk '{print $2}')
comm=$(cat "/proc/$ppid/status" | grep ^Name: | awk '{print $2}')
echo "echo \"$comm\""
```

But this will only work on Linux. `ps` is a bit messy and difficult to use portable, but it's certainly *more portable* than Linux's procfs.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply and your solution! 

I run CentOS6/7/8 on my machine, and by using 

`case '$comm' ` 

I can perfectly adapt my env variables to my liking now. 

Much appreciated, thank you!

rws